# Is there any way to change the default path which Django will use to locate files in generic class based views?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

So I am making a Blog website. I am using Class Bases Views to give the users an ability to add posts, view posts, update and delete them. So in my views.py, I have this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from .models import Post
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

# Create your views here.


def home(request):

    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all()
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import PostListView, PostDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name="home"),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name="post-detail"),
]
```

The problem is in the PostDetailView. When I create a file called post_detail.html in my templates folder, so that when user goes to a specific post in the website, we redirect them to the post_detail.html. But the site says that post_detail.html template cannot be found.

I have learnt that the the generic class based views will be looking for a template with this naming convention, `<app>/<module>_<viewtype>.html`. So it's going to be looking in the directory of the app name, which, in my case, is going to be "blog_app" then a template with a model name which is going to be "Post" and then the view type.

***Is there any way to change the default path which Django will use to locate files in generic class based views?***

So that I can then tell Django to look in my *templates* folder to search for post_detail.html template.

*Note: I have registered my templates folder in the settings.py in the "dirs" like this* `'DIRS': ['templates'],`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to register your project’s templates directory folder then the setting that needs to be modified is `DIRS` inside `TEMPLATES`.

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

The `BASE_DIR` will already exist if you created your project using the default project template.

If `APP_DIRS` option is set to `True` in `TEMPLATES`, then
this is the relative path where your `post_detail.html` should be present.

```
blog_app/templates/blog_app/post_detail.html
```

Comment: Yes. It worked. But you said that this `blog_app/templates/blog_app/post_detail.html` is the path where my post_detail.html should be. I created a blog_app folder inside my templates folder and placed the post_detail.html inside that blog_app folder inside my templates. *Is there any way to change this path which Django looks for my post_detail.html* so that it looks in the templates folder only *not* blog_app?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/overriding-templates/#overriding-templates